# unity Draw directly to a Canvas from Script

Tags: user-interface, canvas, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D I want to draw a GUI in world Space.
Its needed that the UI isnt static. It have to be created from a script.

But I cant figure out how to do this.
Calling GUI:Box() just adds the box to the screen UI.

Edit:

I did some Research and figured out that the GUI Elements are using a Canvas Renderer and a Script.

Its not a problem to add the Canvas Renderer

```
GameObject o = new GameObject(child.OriginalName);
o.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
```

But I cant add the Script.

I also tried to use GUIText Component.

```
o.AddComponent<GUIText>();
o.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
o.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
o.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = child.InnerHtml;
o.GetComponent<GUIText>().font = Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont("Arial", 5);
o.GetComponent<GUIText>().fontSize = 5;
```

But this shows exactly nothing

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? E.g. if you want to enable/disable parts of it, you can simply do that if you use the UI (not the OnGui, those two are not related).

Comment: In Unity, it's fairly common to render the UI with a second camera that *just* draws your UI objects (whether they're 2D, 3D, or whatever). Then you can manipulate those objects however you want.

Comment: I'm no t sure if this is what you are asing for but : http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/849176/how-to-create-a-canvas-and-text-ui-46-object-using.html

Comment: you must be joking "GUI" ?  that is Unity's "old" ux system.  it's no longer available, you might as well be trying to build for Apple Lisa or something, forget it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got this to work, no need for a captain here.

Include this

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

and then u hava access to the UI Components.
For example a Text

```
o.AddComponent<CanvasRenderer>();
o.AddComponent<Text>();
o.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Text"
o.GetComponent<Text>().font = Font.CreateDynamicFontFromOSFont("Arial", 7);
o.GetComponent<Text>().fontSize = 7;
o.GetComponent<Text>().alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleRight;
```

where o is a Gameobject.

just set the Canvas as parent of the GameObject and it works fine